# Variable handling during windows docker build

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile, windows-container

How can i define variables in the `Dockerfile` for a windows image so they are accessible in subsequent `RUN` statements?

My test `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

ARG viaArg=value
ENV viaEnv="""value"""
RUN $viaShell=\"value\"
RUN echo """viaArg: $env:viaArg"""
RUN echo """viaEnv: $env:viaEnv"""
RUN echo """viaShell: $myusername"""
RUN echo """viaShell+env: $env:viaShell"""
```

when building the image via

> PS > docker build -t myImage .

only `viaArg` and `viaEnv` show (a) value.

The first example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45857825/7926064) puts multiple commands in one line like

`RUN $someVar=\"2.60.3\" ; echo $someVar`

but surely there must be a different way.

Is using the `$env` namespace the only possible way?

How does [`setx`](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22017#issuecomment-345272420) take part in all of this?

Note: im not trying to pass [variables from commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39978342/7926064), so [`ARG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495294/7926064) may already be used in a wrong manner. And i dont want to [set the variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44925489/7926064) permanently, they should only exist during the build run, so i dont need them [in the registry](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25988#issuecomment-248436165).

Used versions are

```
PS > docker -v
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
PS > [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version    
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      14393  0
PS > (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ReleaseId).ReleaseId
1607
```

Comment: the only way is with the `ENV or ARG` if you want to use in your environemnt and not save the in the registry. As last commands you can delete them in your dockerfile if this is what you are after.

Comment: You are trying to pass environment variable from your host into build?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian nope, just define some variables that are used in later `RUN` statements, it seemed off to use the `$end:` namespace for that but @Edwin states that is the only possibility. Kind of related is my other linked question.