# Execute powershell script during windows docker build to set environment

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, dockerfile

In order to build my windows docker image, i need to fetch some data from the internet. Unfortunately, there is a proxy in between so i need to configure the build shell environment accordingly.

In order to not display the username and password during every build (which can be seen in the log on e.g. Jenkins) i am trying to execute a powershell script within the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

# set proxy credentials
COPY set_proxy.ps1 C:/Temp/
RUN """ C:/Temp/set_proxy.ps1"""

# download setups from web
RUN Invoke-WebRequest ...
```

and the `set_proxy.ps1` file is the following (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25082595/7926064) and [this](https://martin.hoppenheit.info/blog/2015/using-powershell-behind-proxy/))

```
$username = 'proxyUser'
$password = 'proxyPassword'
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).Proxy.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("""HTTP_PROXY""", """http://$($username):$($password)@proxyHost:proxyPort""", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("""HTTPS_PROXY""", """http://$($username):$($password)@proxyHost:proxyPort""", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

When i execute the `Invoke-WebRequest` within the `set_proxy.ps1` script the download works, if i use the extra `RUN` step, it doesnt work, i get an error message from the proxy.

This might be related to how Docker on Windows [handles variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48282208/7926064).

Comment: you can use a cntlm service to hide your username and password and use that for your docker configuration.

Comment: @Edwin thanks, that can solve the imminent issue but i would like to know if/how it is possible to create some sort of environment from powershell scripts for within the Docker build context. I assume, each `RUN` starts a new shell or something like this.

Comment: I don't get what do you want to achive with this question, because you have asked how to save the variables in your environment in your other question

Comment: @Edwin if i could assign variables in a powershell script so they are available to subsequent `RUN` calls it would help me with this particular problem. But in general i want to be able to modify the shell (e.g. set a global proxy) with a powershell script

Comment: again this is what you've asked in the other question and the answer is what you already thought: using "ENV or ARG" depending how you want to init your global variables.